# CorePlot: Change Axis Increment Label Color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I am working on an implementation of CorePlot that uses a chart with all white elements on a black view.

The chart is coming along nicely, but I cannot get my axis increment labels to be the correct color. To clarify, the labels for the axis are correct (time and usage) but the labels on the axis tick marks are still in black.

What I currently see:

[image]

Changing my view background to white to confirm that the tick labels are there:

[image]

I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction for making the tick mark labels white instead of black, as well as making the horizontal lines that go across the chart white instead of black.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line styles and text styles both have color properties (`lineColor` and `color`, respectively). Use the following axis properties to set the styles:

- `titleTextStyle`: text style for the axis title
- `labelTextStyle`: text style for the labels at the major tick locations
- `minorTickLabelTextStyle`: text style for the labels at the minor tick locations
- `axisLineStyle`: line style for the axis line
- `majorTickLineStyle`: line style for the tick marks at the major tick locations
- `minorTickLineStyle`: line style for the tick marks at the minor tick locations
- `majorGridLineStyle`: line style for the grid lines at the major tick locations
- `minorGridLineStyle`: line style for the grid lines at the minor tick locations

Comment: @arcade16 Your comment was incomplete. I don't see any code in the comment or in the question.